# How to modify parameters in Laravel's cursor paginator

Tags: laravel

In my model, I've defined an accessor that changes the format of a date column. For example, `Y-m-d` to `m/d/Y`.

The problem comes when I use [cursor pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#cursor-pagination) and Laravel takes the value provided by the accessor instead of the raw original value. With an incorrect date format, the MySQL query fails with `Error Code: 1525. Incorrect DATE value`. I need to replace the value for the date column in the cursor parameters but there's no convenient way to do this (for example: attributes are protected).

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually create the cursor and provide it to the [`cursorPaginate`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L2816C5-L2816C5) method.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Cursor;
use Illuminate\Pagination\CursorPaginator;
use App\Models\YourModel;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class YourController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $cursor_paginator = CursorPaginator::resolveCurrentCursor('cursor', null);

        if ($cursor_paginator) {
            $points_to_next_items = $cursor_paginator->pointsToNextItems();
            $parameters = $cursor_paginator->toArray();

            if (array_key_exists('your_date_column', $parameters)) {
                $parameters['your_date_column'] = Carbon::parse($parameters['your_date_column'])->format('Y-m-d');
            }
    
            if (array_key_exists('_pointsToNextItems', $parameters)) {
                unset($parameters['_pointsToNextItems']);
            }

            $new_cursor = new Cursor($parameters, $points_to_next_items);
        } else {
            $new_cursor = null;
        }

        $your_model = YourModel::orderBy('your_date_column', 'DESC');
        $paginated_results = $your_model->cursorPaginate($perPage = 15, $columns = ['*'], $cursorName = 'cursor', $cursor = $new_cursor);
    }
}
```